# selecting only certain tr tags for an xpath in java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

There is some HTML code like this:

```html
<TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <DIV>Address</DIV>
    </TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
    <TD>
      <DIV>1600 Pennsylvania Avenue</DIV>
    </TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
    <TD>
      <DIV>Oval Office</DIV>
    </TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
    <TD>
      <DIV>Washington, DC 22066</DIV>
    </TD>
   </TR>
  </TBODY>
```

This is an example.  The point is the first TR just has the text "Address" and the remaining ones have the actual address.  I would like to make an xpath that just gets the later ones (i.e. not the first one).  Is there a way to use an xpath something like "tbody/tr[>1]".  I can make a little java loop to loop through and just ignore the first one, which I do, but if there is a better way I would be interesting in knowing it.

This is java and eclipse and chrome (though the browser should not matter).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below xpath expression:

```
/TBODY/TR[position()>1]
```

It skips the first TR element and considers only the later.

XPATH Expression:-

```
/TBODY/TR[position()>1]/TD/DIV/text()
```

Output:-

```
Text='1600 Pennsylvania Avenue'
Text='Oval Office'
Text='Washington, DC 22066'
```

Comment: This will be in a list of size 3, right?  Get each element from the list and get the text?

Comment: Yeah O/P shown is only for the list with 3 addresses, but XPATH expression is generic and will work for list with size>3, only condition in the expression is to skip first element. Yes, text method will give you the text value of particular node, that is what you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You will got that with something like: `tbody/tr[preceding-sibling::*]/td/div`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a predicate on the `TR` that has the 'Address' text and then get the following sibling `TR`'s...

```
/TBODY/TR[TD/DIV='Address']/following-sibling::TR/TD/DIV
```